# How to output an array containing only the array to search?

Tags: javascript

The current code returns all found elements if the array contains one element `comp = ['bbb']` see example.
How can I change the code to output the array as a strict match, i.e. log `[[ 'a', 'bbb', 'c' ]]` ?
For other cases, no changes are required.
I've attached the actual code and wrote the output examples.

```
function datasearch() {
 
            let array = [['a', 'bbb', 'c'], ['r', 'bbbfff', 'y',],['w', 'bbbfffkkk', 'u',]]
            let comp = ['bbb'];
            let ans = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {        
                for (el of array[i]) {
                    if (comp.every(y => el.includes(y))) {
                        ans.push(array[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(ans);
            
    }


now
comp = ['bbb']
log [ [ 'a', 'bbb', 'c' ],[ 'r', 'bbbfff', 'y' ],[ 'w', 'bbbfffkkk', 'u' ] ]
```

Expected result for search with **one** array element

```
    comp = ['bbb']
    log [[ 'a', 'bbb', 'c' ]]
```

For other cases, everything is as in the current code
For example:

```
comp = ['bbb','fff']
log  [ [ 'r', 'bbbfff', 'y' ], [ 'w', 'bbbfffkkk', 'u' ] ]
```

Comment: You want only those arrays which only contain **'bbb'** as a separate element, not **'bbbfff'** etc ?

Comment: yes, if the array bbb is given, i.e. containing one element, output it. in all other cases, as a working script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need two separate behaviors, which need to be treated independently.

1. When your search array `comp` has only one element, you need to check for an exact match in the source array `array`.
2. When your search array `comp` contains multiple elements, you only check if the elements are present in the source array (current implementation).

Code will become:

```
function datasearch() {

    let array = [['a', 'bbb', 'c'], ['r', 'bbbfff', 'y',], ['w', 'bbbfffkkk', 'u',]]
    let comp = ['bbb'];
    let ans = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (comp.length == 1) {
          for (el of array[i]) {
            if (el === comp[0]) {
              ans.push(array[i]);
              break;
            }
          }
        } else {
            for (el of array[i]) {
                if (comp.every(y => el.includes(y))) {
                    ans.push(array[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(ans);

}
```

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly. The key point is the two behaviors and comp.length == 1 . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then perhaps such a solution can help you:

```js
function datasearch(comp = [], strictCompare = false) {
  const array = [
    ['a', 'bbb', 'c'],
    ['r', 'bbbfff', 'y', ],
    ['w', 'bbbfffkkk', 'u', ]
  ]
  const ans = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (el of array[i]) {
      if (comp.every(y => (strictCompare) ? el === y : el.includes(y))) {
        ans.push(array[i]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return ans;
}

console.log('not strict', datasearch(['bbb']));
console.log('strict', datasearch(['bbb'], true));
console.log('combine(strict & not strict)', datasearch(['bbb'], true).concat(datasearch(['kkk'])));
```